# Passage from dev to prod creates a difference in adding project container

Tags: symfony, command-line, containers

I created a new command line. The code of the command line calls a business manager class called BatchManager.

Here is the constructor of the BatchManager class :

```
public function __construct(\Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry $doctrine, $mailer, 
        \Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface $translator,
        \Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Debug\TimedTwigEngine $templating,
        $superUserCivilite, $superUserNom, $superUserCourriel)
```

here is the service.yml to declare the BatchManager class as a service

```
 batch_manager:
    class: %batch_manager_class%
    arguments: [@doctrine, @mailer, @translator, @templating, %super_user_civility%, %super_user_name%, %super_user_email%]
```

in dev mode there is no problem but when I add the --env=prod in the command line to call in a production mod I have an exception:

```
Fatal error : argument 4 passed to BatchManager::construct() must be an instance of  \Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Debug\TimedTwigEngine, instance of Symfony/Bundle/Twig... (I cannot read the rest) instead..
```

What is going on ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are type hinting the debug (dev) version specifically in `BatchManager::__construct()` which isn't available in production (or any other environment where debug is set to false).

You should use the interface (`\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface`) instead.